# Gerund appositives

Tags: gerunds, appositives

Can you show me sentences that use gerund clauses(not participial constructions) as a appositive clause as many as possible...

Like “my favorite sport, playing baseball, has brought me friends.” (I know it sounds unnatural though..)

Comment: Isn’t that participial construction?

Comment: Oops, yes, you are right. Deleted.

Comment: >>Pkjmm
Isn’t the latter one participial construction?

Comment: My favourite pastime, fishing, is not that much more difficult under the latest anti-Covid rules. [Don't take this as necessarily true.]

Comment: Appositives are noun phrases, not clauses. In your example "playing basketball" is a non-finite clause and hence not an appositive but a supplement in NP structure. We know it's a clause because "playing" has "basketball" as object and thus must be a verb.

Comment: By that definition, no clause can be a noun phrase, so the question is answered because gerunds are clauses and appositives are noun phrases. For this terminology. Others will, of course, differ.

Comment: Incidentally, we know it's a supplement because the indicator "namely" can be added, as in "My favorite sport, namely playing baseball, has brought me friends".